# g_mass_storage - select usb port

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

At my Development board (imx6) I have two USB OTG ports:

```
ls /sys/class/udc 
ci_hdrc.0  ci_hdrc.1
```

When I setup the mass storage with

```
modprobe g_mass_storage file=/tmp/lun0.img
```

then automatically the USB port ci_hdrc.0 is used for this.

Is there a possibility to configure, which USB port shall be used for the g_mass_storage?
In my case, I would like to use ci_hdrc.1 instead of ci_hdrc.0.

Comment: Yes, there’s a possibility.

Comment: @0andriy: Ok, can you explain it how this can be used that an alternative USB port will be used?

Answer (score 1):

As there is no further information from someone, here is a short result from my investigation:
It seems to be the more modern approach to setup USB gadgets via **libcomposite** (configfs based) instead of **g_mass_storage**.
There, you have the possibility to link the USB-gadget with the USB device controller.

Here the solution, which works for me:

```
###############################
# Create backing file         #
###############################

dd bs=1M count=16 if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/lun0.img
parted /tmp/lun0.img mklabel msdos
parted -f --align=minimal /tmp/lun0.img mkpart primary fat32 0% 100%
mkfs.vfat /tmp/lun0.img

###############################
# Mount file                  #
###############################

losetup /dev/loop7 /tmp/lun0.img
mount /dev/loop7 /mnt/usb

###############################
# Configure USB gadget        #
###############################
modprobe libcomposite

cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir g1
cd g1

###############################
# Populate Device-Level Stuff #
###############################

echo "0x1d6b" > idVendor  # Linux Foundation - must be adopted by your ID
echo "0x0104" > idProduct # multi gadget - must be adopted by your ProductID
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice   # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB      # USB 2.0

# English language strings...
mkdir strings/0x409

echo "0123456789" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "foo" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "bar" > strings/0x409/product

mkdir configs/c.1
mkdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "USB Mass Storage config" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration

#
# Create mass_storage config
#
mkdir functions/mass_storage.usb0

# link the mount point which shall be used for usb_mass_storage
mkdir functions/mass_storage.usb0/lun.0 
echo "/tmp/lun0.img" > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/mass_storage.usb0/lun.0/file
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/mass_storage.usb0/lun.0/removable

# associate function with config
ln -s functions/mass_storage.usb0 configs/c.1

#bind..
# you need to replace this line with the platform-specific UDC.
# Use 'ls /sys/class/udc' to see available UDCs
echo "ci_hdrc.1" > UDC
```

The approach to link the usb gadget with an USB device controler can be used for each other usb gadget like ACM, ECM, NCM, RNDIS, ...